# Upload multiple image doesn't store to databased and path folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making upload multiple image and stored to one field. But I have a proble with my code, images can't store to database and to path folder. May be you can help me please

This is my controller

```
    public function post() {
      if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        $data = array(  'id_merk'                   => $this->input->post('id_merk'),
                        'createdAt'                 => $this->input->post('createdAt')
        );

        // var_dump($data);
        $this->m_barang->post( $data );
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'success');
        redirect('admin/merk');
      } else {
        $count = count($_FILES['file']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $value){
          for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
            $_FILES['file']['name']     = $value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['file']['type']     = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['file']['error']    = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['file']['size']     = $value['size'][$s];   
              // $config['file_name'] = 'pict_'.date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').'.jpg';
              $config['upload_path'] = './upload/be/barang';
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG';
              $config['max_size'] = '8000';
              $config['max_width']  = '1366';
              $config['max_height']  = '1024';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();

            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
          }
        }
        $names = implode(', ', $name_array);

        $data = array(  'id_merk'                   => $this->input->post('id_merk'),
                        'photo_barang'              => $names
        );
        $this->m_barang->post( $data );
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'gambar ada');
        redirect('admin/merk');
      }
    }
```

and this is my view

```
    <input class="form-control" name="file[]" id="files" type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

Please, can you help me how to fix my problem with my code?

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this?

Comment: Why you are using two different loops?

Comment: At the last time, I've been tried like this [link](https://arjunphp.com/multiple-image-uploading-using-single-input-codeigniter/) and it's work for me, but I don't know why my code doesn't work upload multiple image sir

Answer (score 0):

**First**, Use only 1 loop to upload the multiple images.

**Second**, give name attribute of `<input type="file">` to `$this->upload->do_upload()`

**Third**, if uploading path inside the application folder then use `APPPATH.'upload/be/barang'` or if outside the application folder use `FCPATH.'upload/be/barang'`

```
 $count = count($_FILES['file']['size']);
 for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
    $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['file']['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['file']['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['file']['error']    = $_FILES['file']['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['file']['size'][$s];   
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/be/barang';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG';
    $config['max_size'] = '8000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1366';
    $config['max_height']  = '1024';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        //image uploading error
    }else{
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
    }


 }
```

Comment: I was use anyway for upload multiple image but now the problem is image uploaded just one sir

Comment: what is the result of this line `$count = count($_FILES['file']['size']);` ?